# Component dosen't work in all ionic views

Tags: html, typescript, ionic2, components

I'm working on an Ionic 2 project and I'm using a component called "offre". 
I have got a problem running this component. It works correctly in the home page but not in the views (check [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yY8L.png) to see the error)
The data from firebase shown correctly in home.html but not in the other views!
Any suggestions?

Offre.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database"; 
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'offre',
  templateUrl: 'offre.html'
})
export class OffreComponent {

  text: string;
  datas: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  user : any ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db: AngularFireDatabase, public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    this.datas=db.list('/posts');
    console.log('Hello OffreComponent Component');

  }
```

Comment: Do you have some code for us please?

Comment: @Wernerson done !